# Proper way to Call Props in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following code:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                auth === true ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
                )
            }
        />
    );
}

function PublicRoute({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) {
    return <Route {...rest} render={props => (auth === false ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/dashboard" />)} />;
}

export default () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <PublicRoute auth={true} path="/login" exact component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute auth={true} path="/news" exact component={News} />
            <PrivateRoute auth={false} path="/blogs" exact component={Blog} />
            <Route render={() => <h3>No Match</h3>} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

I want to add this below to keep track of the authenticated prop:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.authenticated
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(?);
```

However, I'm not sure how to add it to the functional code. Would I need to convert the export default section to a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I'm not sure how to add it to the functional code. Would I need to convert the export default section to a class?

No, you don't. You only need to convert a functional component to a class based component if you want to use state, lifecycle methods or refs (and arguably not even in these cases since the arrival of [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)).

Simply put your exported component in a variable instead of exporting it, and use that variable with connect:

```
const RouterComponent = ({ auth }) => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <PublicRoute auth={auth} path="/login" exact component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute auth={auth} path="/news" exact component={News} />
            <PrivateRoute auth={auth} path="/blogs" exact component={Blog} />
            <Route render={() => <h3>No Match</h3>} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.authenticated
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RouterComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please don't do unnamed default exports, you can rewrite it into this:

```
const MyRouter = (props) => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <PublicRoute auth={true} path="/login" exact component={Login} />
            <PrivateRoute auth={true} path="/news" exact component={News} />
            <PrivateRoute auth={false} path="/blogs" exact component={Blog} />
            <Route render={() => <h3>No Match</h3>} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

and then you can easily(Also note, that you can have only one default export from file).

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyRouter);
```

Note, that I added `props` as an argument to `MyRouter` component. Now you can use props inside of it and pass `auth={props.auth}` to your `PrivateRoute` components.